# Bootstrap submenu doesn't work well on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navbar with this code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand px-5" href="index.php">
          <img src="img/logo.png" width="110" height="70">
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
                aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item px-4">
              <a class="nav-link active text-white" href="index.php">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-white" href="" id="navbarDropdown1" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                   aria-expanded="false">Categories</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                  <?php
                  $sql1 = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE id IN (SELECT parent FROM categories) AND parent = ? AND deleted = ?");
                  $sql1->bind_param('ii', $var0, $var0);
                  $sql1->execute();
                  $result1 = $sql1->get_result();
                  while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)){
                    $test = $row1['id'];
                    ?>

                    <li class="nav-item dropend">
                    <a class="nav-link active dropdown-toggle" href="" id="navbarDropdown1" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                       aria-expanded="false"><?=$row1['category'];?></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                      <?php
                      $sql2 = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent IN (SELECT id FROM categories) AND parent = ? AND deleted = ?");
                      $sql2->bind_param('ii', $row1['id'], $var0);
                      $sql2->execute();
                      $result2 = $sql2->get_result();
                      while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)){ ?>

                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="category.php?cat=<?=$row2['id'];?>"><?=$row2['category'];?></a></li>

                  <?php } ?>

                  </ul>

                  <?php }
                       $sql3 = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT parent FROM categories) AND parent = ? AND deleted = ?");
                       $sql3->bind_param('ii', $var0, $var0);
                       $sql3->execute();
                       $result3 = $sql3->get_result();
                       while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3)){ ?>

                          <li><a class="nav-link active" href="category.php?cat=<?=$row3['id'];?>"><?=$row3['category'];?></a></li>

                        <?php } ?>

                </ul>
            </li>
          </li>
            <li class="nav-item px-4">
              <a class="nav-link active text-white" href="about.php">About</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
// make it as accordion for smaller screens
        if (window.innerWidth > 992) {
            document.querySelectorAll('.navbar .nav-item').forEach(function(everyitem){
                everyitem.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e){
                    let el_link = this.querySelector('a[data-bs-toggle]');
                    if(el_link != null){
                        let nextEl = el_link.nextElementSibling;
                        el_link.classList.add('show');
                        nextEl.classList.add('show');
                    }
                });
                everyitem.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(e){
                    let el_link = this.querySelector('a[data-bs-toggle]');
                    if(el_link != null){
                        let nextEl = el_link.nextElementSibling;
                        el_link.classList.remove('show');
                        nextEl.classList.remove('show');
                    }
                })
            });
        }
// end if innerWidth
    });
    // DOMContentLoaded  end
</script>
```

and this css file:

```
.dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu, .dropend:hover > .dropdown-menu{
  position: block;
  margin-top: .125em;
  margin-left: .125em;
}

@media screen and (min-width:769px){
  .dropend:hover > .dropdown-menu{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
  }
}
```

Now the weird problem is when I open the website on mobile on 400x652 dimension the menu dropdown doesn't work at all. And if it is on 500x589 dimension the menu dropdown works but the submenu dropdown doesn't work, it closes the menu dropdown instead. I also tried to remove all css but still. Where is the issue, and how to fix it?

Comment: I don't know exactly what is causing the problem, however, `position: block` is invalid. The only valid values for the "position" property are: static, relative, absolute, fixed, sticky.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: @TimR I tried to remove all css but still the issue exists ... How can I fix it then ?? :(